# SAN topology and discovery

Tags: virtual-machine, storage, san, emc

I'm working on SAN topology. Using SMI-s server I have discovered Clariion storage and I have LUN and ESXi server relationship but I need on which switch these are connected. How to find the storage FC is connected in which switch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into FC-switches to get list of WWNs registered on ports, zoning information, nameserver data. For Brocade switches you can use SSH or HTTPS to log into the switches or interact with Brocade Network Advisor (BNA).